# Interpretation of Changes introduced by ti() in Logistic GAM Modeling

Tags: logistic, interpretation, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am currently working on a logistic regression model using the mgcv package.
The mode contains 3 variables (x1 and x2, continuous) and x3 (categorical) and I believe there is interaction between the variables x1 and x2.
This is my base model:

`gam_model <- gam(Output ~ s(x1) + s(x2) + x3, method = "REML", data = data, family = binomial, select = TRUE)`

And this is the output:

```
Formula:
Output ~ s(x1) + s(x2) + x3

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   2.5464     0.4327   5.886 3.97e-09 ***
x31      -0.1607     0.5105  -0.315    0.753    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
          edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value    
s(x1) 3.9614      9  34.72  <2e-16 ***
s(x2) 0.9836      9  51.69  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.664   Deviance explained = 63.9%
-REML = 65.942  Scale est. = 1         n = 263
> gam.check(gam_model)

Method: REML   Optimizer: outer newton
full convergence after 20 iterations.
Gradient range [-2.632544e-05,1.312618e-05]
(score 65.9424 & scale 1).
Hessian positive definite, eigenvalue range [1.746351e-07,0.7026972].
Model rank =  20 / 20 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

          k'   edf k-index p-value  
s(x1) 9.000 3.961    1.01   0.470  
s(x2) 9.000 0.984    0.92   0.095
```

Now, when introducing ti, the output changes drastically, but the deviance explained remains relatively constant:

```
gam_model <- gam(Output ~ ti(x1) + ti(x2) + ti(x1, x2) + x3, method = "REML", data = data, family = binomial, select = TRUE)

Formula:
Output ~ ti(x1) + ti(x2) + ti(x1, x2) + x3

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   1.9417     0.4147   4.682 2.84e-06 ***
x31      -0.3893     0.5092  -0.764    0.445    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                  edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value    
ti(x1)     5.161e-06      4   0.00   0.475    
ti(x2)     9.774e-01      4  36.07  <2e-16 ***
ti(x1,x2) 5.519e+00     16  39.94  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =   0.66   Deviance explained = 64.9%
-REML = 65.132  Scale est. = 1         n = 263
> gam.check(gam_model)

Method: REML   Optimizer: outer newton
full convergence after 15 iterations.
Gradient range [-2.806258e-05,9.209817e-06]
(score 65.132 & scale 1).
Hessian positive definite, eigenvalue range [3.756572e-07,1.244895].
Model rank =  26 / 26 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

                  k'      edf k-index p-value  
ti(x1)     4.00e+00 5.16e-06    0.98   0.425  
ti(x2)     4.00e+00 9.77e-01    0.91   0.085 .
ti(x1,x2) 1.60e+01 5.52e+00    0.89   0.025 *
```

Would somebody help me explain the results and the changes?

Q1: X1 and X2 are closely correlated and in other applications of this model I often see s(x1) going to a value close to zero while s(x2) increases when I add using select = TRUE to the commands. Is this due to the interaction?

Q2: In this specific case, I am not certain how to interpret the strong drop in ti(x1) and the high interaction term, especially in the context of a low p-value the gam.check function. My initial thought is that the effect of ti(x1) is mostly driven by interaction via ti(x2), which is now "separated", but is this true, and could I use this model?

Thank you very much for your help